# How to force Joda-Time to parse only part of String?

Tags: java, jodatime

let's assume I have following dates (in String):

```
2009-05-15T23:00:00
2009-05-15T23:00:00.000Z 
2009-05-15
```

I don't care about the time and zone, only date is relevant for me. So I want to try to parse it with following pattern:

yyyy-MM-dd

I try to parse it using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

```
DateTimeFormat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
format.withZone(zone).parseDateTime(string).toLocalDate();
```

and I get following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2009-05-15T23:00:00.000Z" is malformed at "T23:00:00.000Z"
```

Is there a way how to force Joda-Time to ignore rest of the string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem, multiple date formats where I just wanted to ignore everything after a certain point. What I did was create a consume all DateTimeParser and then add that using a DateTimeFormatterBuilder.

I believe this would meet your needs:

**JodaDateTimeConsumeAll.java:**

```
public class JodaDateTimeConsumeAll implements DateTimeParser{

    @Override
    public int estimateParsedLength() {
        return 100;
    }

    @Override
    public int parseInto(DateTimeParserBucket bucket, String text, int position) {
        return text.length(); //consume the whole thing
    }

}
```

**FormatterBuilder:**

```
DateTimeParser dtp = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendYear(4,4)
    .appendLiteral("-")
    .appendDayOfMonth(2)
    .appendLiteral("-")
    .appendMonthOfYear(2)
    .append(new JodaDateTimeConsumeAll())
    .toFormatter()
    .getParser();
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the relevant substring; `2009-05-15` and parse that with pattern `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: Thanks - the point is, that i have lots of formats that might differ in the last part...

Comment: @krtek: well, a substring(0, 10) would match 2009-05-15 in all of cases you mentioned ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you will first need to match the string pattern, then pass that matched substring to jodatime.

Answer (score 0):

You can always ignore the Timezone after the date has successfully been parsed.

For now use the pattern (for your date string format `2009-05-15T23:00:00.000Z`)

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'
```

Are your date format the same throughout your application or are they different?

---

Based on your edited post, it seems you don't really need the time part, so just get the relevant first 10 characters of the date string and parse it with `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Comment: Date format can be very different as they come from different sources - please see reformatted question.